# VBA: insert formula with dynamic range and relative reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have done a lot of searching and trial and error and I still haven't been able to find an answer for my question.

I would like to fill a range in sheet2 with a formula that refers to a dynamic range in sheet1. I have used the piece of code that I have pasted below, and it works perfectly so far.

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim x as Integer

Set rng=worksheets(sheet2).Range("J6:J9")
x = 21

    With sheet1
        LastCol = .Cells(21, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        c.Formula = "=sheet1!" & Cells(j, LastCol).Address
        j = j + 1
    Next c
```

My problem is that this code creates an absolute reference, and I need a relative (or mixed) since I need to be able to do some "dragging" of cells later on. I have tried using formulaR1C1, but I can't get it to work with dynamic ranges.

I would be very happy if anyone can help me and if you need me to explain anything feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you are actually searching for this:

```
.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

The address has 5 properties - `.Address(RowAbsolute, ColumnAbsolute, ReferenceStyle, External, RelativeTo)`

As far as these are the first two parameters from the 5 in the .Address, you may call them like this:

```
.Address(False, False)
```

or even like this:

```
.Address(0, 0)
```

And some additional hints to what Peh already mentioned - do not use Integers in VBA - [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am using `.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)`.  I had actually already tried using `.Address(False,False)` and `.Address(0,0)`, but didn't know why + it didn't help. And thanks for the hints :) I am fairly new to VBA, so I appreciate all the tips and tricks I can get :)

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for …

```
.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Having a look into the Microsoft VBA References sometimes helps: [Range.Address Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

Also, this reference should be fully qualified with the worksheet name and not left to the relative context:

```
Cells(j, LastCol).Address
```

Comment: Thank you so much for :) I went with @Vityata, but I really appreciate your help and the "VBA Best practices" etc.  I am fairly new to VBA, so I appreciate all the tips and tricks I can get :)